# Close dialog box won't open in close vote review queue

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, vote-to-close

I'm trying to review a question with a close vote on it in the close vote queue, but the vote to close button won't open the dialog box. The edit button works fine, but the close button does nothing. I tried a hard refresh a few times, but no dice. I'm using `Chrome 23.0.1271.97`. I just noticed this behavior on GFH SE and Music SE. I could post a screenshot with freehand circles, but I don't think that would show much else.

Comment: Originally posted here. http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/465/1678

Comment: Hey Luke, do you by chance have Rob's ["View Vote Totals Without 1000 Reputation" Script](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/4812) installed? There was a bug in it that caused this issue, and that bug has since been fixed, if you update the script to the latest version. The bug was in version 1.5.1, and I think he's now released 1.5.2. Looks like mine updated automatically...

Comment: Yes, I just installed it a few days ago. I'll see if it needs updating.

Comment: @jmort253 I just updated it to 1.5.2 and it works fine now. It didn't even occur to me that this could have had to do with that extension. Was that a known problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Troubleshooting 101:**

Before reporting a user interface bug in Stack Exchange, the first step is to disable all of your browser extensions and see if the problem still exists. If the problem disappears after disabling all extensions, then it may help to instead report the bug to the extension developer on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).

Before you can report the bug, you need to determine which extension is the problem. By systematically enabling one extension at a time and repeating the steps that produce the problem, one can determine the exact add-on that's causing the problem through a process of elimination.

Once you determine which extension/add-on, or script is the problem, go to the post on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) and let the creator know about the bug.

Of course, you can always crack open the code and try to fix the issue yourself and then submit the fix to the developer. :)

In this case, I already reported the problem, and it has been fixed.  **It was fixed back in November, according to Rob W, the author of the add-on.**

Comment: I installed the extension just a few days ago from the chrome web store. I don't know why it downloaded 1.5.1, though.